# Why is there a second line outputted for the sys.stdout.write()?

Tags: python-3.x

Im just a beginner trying to get head around some basic concepts.

```py
X = 1; Y = 2
>>> print(X, Y) # Print: the easy way
1 2
>>> import sys # Print: the hard way
>>> sys.stdout.write(str(X) + ' ' + str(Y) + '\n')
1 2
4
#Also if i open a file and write to it; prints '4' on the interactive terminal
>>>open('temp2', 'w').write(str(X) + ' ' + str(Y) + '\n')  # Send to file 
4
```

Why is 4 being printed.

Comment: Reformat the code, use 3 backticks `

Comment: Check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks#:~:text=Use%20fenced%20code,the%20opening%20fence

Comment: Anyway, the 4 returned should be the number of characters written on the file, add spaces and see that the number returned increases. `.write()` returns the number of characters written.

Answer (score 0):

[`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.write) returns the number of bytes written according to the documentation:

> Write the given bytes-like object, b, and return the number of bytes
> written (always equal to the length of b in bytes,

Answer (score 0):

Using sys.stdout.write() outputs the given argument and also returns the number of bytes that was outputted. So, in your code, ‘1 2’ is printed by the write() function and then 4 is printed, which is the number of bytes that ‘1 2’ uses.